# Access 2010 For Each on Form.Controls

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am very new to VBA so trying to get my head around the differences with C#.
I currently have a Sub to conduct a batch import that only works on a single row/record selected from a datasheet subform.

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

    Dim strBatchID As String
    On Error GoTo NoBatch
    Me.subClaimsToProcessLookup.Form.Controls.Item("txtBatchID").SetFocus
    strBatchID = Me.subClaimsToProcessLookup.Form.Controls.Item("txtBatchID").Text
    GoTo ContinueImport

NoBatch:
    MsgBox "Please select a row", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion, Me.Caption
    Exit Sub

ContinueImport:
    If Not IsNumeric(strBatchID) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a row", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion, Me.Caption
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim lngUserID As Long

'...process continues here...
```

This will only process whichever row the user has selected...now the user would like to simply process all the rows in the datasheet from one button click.

I am wondering if a For Each would work for this, versus having to use the record navigation
(Move Next, etc), which I'm not very familiar with...but For Each is a simple concept for me from C#.
As in:
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

```
Dim strBatchID As String
On Error GoTo NoBatch
' Add loop here to go through each item in the datasheet view and process it. 
For Each Me.subClaimsToProcessLookup.Form.Controls.Item("txtBatchID").Text in Me.subClaimsToProcessLookup.Form.Controls
    Me.subClaimsToProcessLookup.Form.Controls.Item("txtBatchID").SetFocus
    strBatchID = Me.subClaimsToProcessLookup.Form.Controls.Item("txtBatchID").Text
    GoTo ContinueImport
Next
```

NoBatch:
    MsgBox "Please select a row", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion, Me.Caption
    'Exit Sub
    Continue For

ContinueImport:
    If Not IsNumeric(strBatchID) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a row", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion, Me.Caption
        'Exit Sub
        Continue For
    End If

```
Dim lngUserID As Long
....process continues here....
```

Also, if a For Each will do this properly, have I set up my 'Continue For' flow correctly?

In summary, I am looking for 1) Confirmation that Form.Controls can be used as a collection in For Each;
and 2) That I have put in correct flow control (Continue For) for the For Each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
   ''The recordset from the subform
   Set rs = Me.subClaimsToProcessLookup.Form.Recordset
   Do While Not rs.EOF
       ''Each record in the subform recordset
       sId = rs!ID
       MsgBox sId ''Just to check
       ''Do stuff with id
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was totally going to over-engineer that loop otherwise.